# Where to download older Blender versions? Namely Blender 2.80

Tags: versions

Where to download Blender 2.80?

I downloaded Blender 2.82a but it always crashes.
So I'd like to try 2.80 but I can't find it on the official Blender site.

Comment: If you're downgrading due to crashes, perhaps you'd prefer 2.79b instead. It's the last stable release before the UI change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have all Blender versions
https://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: Which can actually be found through the official site. Download => Previous Versions => All Previous Versions. The download link in that box goes to the site in this answer.